# How do I import a npm module and function from another file when developing for a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a Chrome extension using Manifest V3. This is a part of my manifest.json which declares a service worker.

```
    "background": {
        "type": "module",
        "service_worker": "ui/backend/service-worker.js"
    }
```

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: { path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"), filename: "bundle.js" },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html",
        }),
    ],
    devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
};
```

Inside my service-worker.js, this is all I do.

```
import { initTracker } from "./tracker.js";
import Browser from "webextension-polyfill";

initTracker();
```

Inside my tracker.js file, I just have some basic functions defined. I am using Webpack as my module bundler. How can I make sure that I can use the webextension-polyfill module and its APIs within my chrome extension and its service worker? I currently get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "webextension-polyfill". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

```
Service worker registration failed. Status code: 15
```

Comment: The error means your webpack config is incorrect as it didn't compile the file at all.

Comment: I have included my webpack.config, I am unable to include the module inside the repo.

Comment: Your config only processes `index`. You need a separate entry for the background script.